# Store with only Downloadable Products. What would you change in order to give a better User Experience?

Tags: magento2, downloadable, virtual-products

In my Magento store there are only downloadable products. I'm thinking to change some things in order to make my store more "Downloadable oriented".

E.g. I was thinking:

- to replace the **Add To Cart** label button with **Download Now** (but maybe this is not a good idea since it could lead to confusion. What do you think?)
- to prevent add more than 1 time the same item

What do you think? What would you change in order to achieve this?

Comment: You can remove address field if you no need to send billing to address.
As Shipping address already gone as you have downloadable product but you can remove city,zip code etc from billing address also.

Comment: @FeedlayTechnologies what about replacing **Add To Cart** text button with **Download now**? Could this lead to misunderstanding in the customer? How to emphasize the fact it's a digital product and it can be downloaded immediately?